# C++ cannot call lambda expression from map

Tags: c++, c++11

I have created a class for temperature conversions and I've decided to create a conversion table with a structure like this:

```
temperature | conversion formula
```

For this reason, I've created a `std::map` that has the key as temperature index and then the formula. Here you can see the implementation:

```
enum class TempType {Celsius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin, Rankine, Delisle, Newton, Reaumur, Romer};

class Temperature {
private:

  double value;   //value of the temperature
  TempType kind;  //Celsius, Fahrenheit...

  //conversion tables
  std::map<TempType, std::function<double(double)>> fromCelsius = {
      { TempType::Fahrenheit, [](double x) { return x * (9/5) + 32; } },
      { TempType::Kelvin, [](double x) { return x + 273.15; } },
      { TempType::Rankine, [](double x) { return (x + 273.15) * (9/5); } },
      { TempType::Delisle, [](double x) { return (100 - x) * (3/2); } },
      { TempType::Reaumur, [](double x) { return x * (33/100); } },
      { TempType::Newton, [](double x) { return x * (4/5); } },
      { TempType::Romer, [](double x) { return x * (21/40) + 7.5; } }
  };

  std::map<TempType, std::function<double(double)>> fromFahrenheit = {
      { TempType::Celsius, [](double x) { return (x - 32) * (5/9); } },
      { TempType::Kelvin, [](double x) { return (x + 459.67) * (5/9); } },
      { TempType::Rankine, [](double x) { return x + 459.67; } },
      { TempType::Delisle, [](double x) { return (212 - x) * (5/6); } },
      { TempType::Newton, [](double x) { return (x - 32) * (11/60); } },
      { TempType::Reaumur, [](double x) { return (x - 32) * (4/9); } },
      { TempType::Romer, [](double x) { return (x - 32) * (7/24) + 7.5; } }
  };

  std::map<TempType, std::function<double(double)>> fromKelvin = {
      { TempType::Celsius, [](double x) { return x - 273.15; } },
      { TempType::Fahrenheit, [](double x) { return x * (9/5) - 459.67; } },
      { TempType::Rankine, [](double x) { return x * (9/5); } },
      { TempType::Delisle, [](double x) { return (373.15 - x) * (3/2); } },
      { TempType::Newton, [](double x) { return (x - 273.15) * (33/100); } },
      { TempType::Reaumur, [](double x) { return (x - 273.15) * (4/5); } },
      { TempType::Romer, [](double x) { return (x - 273.15) * (21/40) + 7.5; } }
  };

  std::map<TempType, std::function<double(double)>> fromRankine = {
      { TempType::Celsius, [](double x) { return (x - 491.67) * (5/9); } },
      { TempType::Fahrenheit, [](double x) { return x - 459.67; } },
      { TempType::Kelvin, [](double x) { return x * (5/9); } },
      { TempType::Delisle, [](double x) { return (671.67 - x) * (5/6); } },
      { TempType::Newton, [](double x) { return (x - 491.67) * (11/60); } },
      { TempType::Reaumur, [](double x) { return (x - 491.67) * (4/9); } },
      { TempType::Romer, [](double x) { return (x - 491.67) * (7/24) + 7.5; } }
  };

  std::map<TempType, std::function<double(double)>> fromDelisle = {
      { TempType::Celsius, [](double x) { return 100 - x * (5/9); } },
      { TempType::Fahrenheit, [](double x) { return 212 - x * (6/5); } },
      { TempType::Kelvin, [](double x) { return 373.15 - x * (2/3); } },
      { TempType::Rankine, [](double x) { return 671.67 - x * (6/5); } },
      { TempType::Newton, [](double x) { return 33 - x * (11/50); } },
      { TempType::Reaumur, [](double x) { return 80 - x * (8/15); } },
      { TempType::Romer, [](double x) { return 60 - x * (7/20); } }
  };

  std::map<TempType, std::function<double(double)>> fromNewton = {
      { TempType::Celsius, [](double x) { return x * (100/33); } },
      { TempType::Fahrenheit, [](double x) { return x * (60/11) + 32; } },
      { TempType::Kelvin, [](double x) { return x * (100/33) + 273.15; } },
      { TempType::Rankine, [](double x) { return x * (60/11) + 491.67; } },
      { TempType::Delisle, [](double x) { return (33 - x) * (50/11); } },
      { TempType::Reaumur, [](double x) { return x * (80/33); } },
      { TempType::Romer, [](double x) { return x * (35/22) + 7.5; } }
  };

  std::map<TempType, std::function<double(double)>> fromReamur = {
      { TempType::Celsius, [](double x) { return x * (5/4); } },
      { TempType::Fahrenheit, [](double x) { return x * (9/4) + 32; } },
      { TempType::Kelvin, [](double x) { return x * (5/4) + 273.15; } },
      { TempType::Rankine, [](double x) { return x * (9/4) + 491.67; } },
      { TempType::Delisle, [](double x) { return (80 - x) * (15/8); } },
      { TempType::Newton, [](double x) { return x * (33/80); } },
      { TempType::Romer, [](double x) { return x * (21/32) + 7.5; } }
  };

  std::map<TempType, std::function<double(double)>> fromRomer = {
      { TempType::Celsius, [](double x) { return (x - 7.5) * (40/21); } },
      { TempType::Fahrenheit, [](double x) { return (x - 7.5) * (24/7) + 32; } },
      { TempType::Kelvin, [](double x) { return (x - 7.5) * (40/21) + 273.15; } },
      { TempType::Rankine, [](double x) { return (x - 7.5) * (24/7) + 491.67; } },
      { TempType::Delisle, [](double x) { return (60 - x) * (20/7); } },
      { TempType::Newton, [](double x) { return (x - 7.5) * (22/35); } },
      { TempType::Reaumur, [](double x) { return (x - 7.5) * (32/21); } }
  };

public:
}    
#endif // TEMPERATURE_H
```

Now, if I want to convert from a temperature object to another, I use this code:

```
Temperature x(20, TempType::Celsius); //20 °C
double s = x.convertTo(TempType::Fahrenheit); //convert 20 °c to 68 °F
```

The conversion code is this:

```
double Temperature::convertTo(const TempType& temperature) const {

  if (temperature == kind) {
    return value;
  }

  double result = -1;

  switch (temperature) {
    case TempType::Celsius:
      result = fromCelsius.at(kind)(value);
      break;
    case TempType::Fahrenheit:
      result = fromFahrenheit.at(kind)(value);
      break;
    case TempType::Kelvin:
      result = fromKelvin.at(kind)(value);
      break;
    case TempType::Rankine:
      result = fromRankine.at(kind)(value);
      break;
    case TempType::Delisle:
      result = fromDelisle.at(kind)(value);
      break;
    case TempType::Newton:
      result = fromNewton.at(kind)(value);
      break;
    case TempType::Reaumur:
      result = fromReamur.at(kind)(value);
      break;
    case TempType::Romer:
      result = fromRomer.at(kind)(value);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }

  return result;

}
```

I use the key of the map (a `TempType`) and then I pass to the lambda the parameter. The result returned is always 0. Any idea?

I am using QTCreator and mingw.

Comment: I think a map of maps would make `convertTo` much simpler, don't you?

Comment: It was the next step because this issue was stopping me, I thought that there were an error in the map code!

Comment: Note that `std::function` is not a lambda. Lambdas are special; when you write a lambda, the compiler creates a unique class/struct with an `operator()` whose body is the body of your lambda. `std::function` is more heavy-weight. You can assign any compatible lambda to it, as well as any type with an `operator()` that is compatible.

Comment: @Justin I'm not a c++ expert so I ask you a suggestion: reading your comment, should I replace the std::function with double(*)(double)? ( = is a function pointer better than a std::function in this case?)

Comment: Your conversion table maps should be static members of `Temperature`, otherwise you'll end up with a copy of them in every `Temperature` object you create.

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi It depends. In almost all cases, you probably just want to use `std::function`. It's good. My comment was just trying to teach terminology: `std::function` is not a lambda, lambdas are not `std::function`s. It's a common misconception and I wanted to correct it. Although looking through the question again, you may already understand that, and I might just be misreading...

Comment: @Justin yes maybe I didnt explain well due to my english but I got it! std::function accepts callables and so it can have lambdas. Thank you by the way!

Comment: You could convert in two steps, for example choosing `Kelvin` as the "middle man". `[from any]` -> `[to Kelvin]` -> `[to other]` and you would only need 14 conversion functions.

Comment: @super Came to my mind as well. It reduces code complexity from _quadratic_ to _linear_.

Comment: I'd even supply a unity lambda to convert from Kelvin to Kelvin .... just so you don't have to special-case it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++ `4/5`, `21/40`, `5/6` and the like are all zero because the division is performed in integer arithmetic.

You need to write `4./5` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @6502's answer said, your `convertTo()` logic is backwards. You want to convert the `value` *from* `kind` *to* `temperature`, so you should be using `switch(kind)` instead of `switch(temperature)`.

The example you show wants to convert `Celsius` to `Fahrenheit`, so `convertTo()` should be calling `fromCelsius.at(Fahrenheit)(value)` instead of calling `fromFahrenheit.at(Celcius)(value)`.  The algorithm you have in the `Fahrenheit` entry of `fromCelsius` is the correct Celsius-to-Fahrenheit conversion.  The algorithm you have in the `Celcius` entry of `fromFahrenheit` is the Fahrenheit-to-Celsius conversion.

This also helps because if `kind` doesn't define a conversion to the specified `temperature` type, a runtime error will be thrown by `std::map::at()`.

`convertTo()` should look more like this:

```
double Temperature::convertTo(const TempType& temperature) const
{
  if (temperature == kind) {
    return value;
  }

  switch (kind) {
    case TempType::Celsius:
      return fromCelsius.at(temperature)(value);
    case TempType::Fahrenheit:
      return fromFahrenheit.at(temperature)(value);
    case TempType::Kelvin:
      return fromKelvin.at(temperature)(value);
    case TempType::Rankine:
      return fromRankine.at(temperature)(value);
    case TempType::Delisle:
      return fromDelisle.at(temperature)(value);
    case TempType::Newton:
      return fromNewton.at(temperature)(value);
    case TempType::Reaumur:
      return fromReamur.at(temperature)(value);
    case TempType::Romer:
      return fromRomer.at(temperature)(value);
  }    

  return -1; // or throw an exception...
}
```

Or, maybe something more like this:

```
double Temperature::convertTo(const TempType& temperature) const
{
  if (temperature == kind) {
    return value;
  }

  std::function<double(double)> convert;

  switch (kind) {
    case TempType::Celsius:
      convert = fromCelsius.at(temperature);
      break;
    case TempType::Fahrenheit:
      convert = fromFahrenheit.at(temperature);
      break;
    case TempType::Kelvin:
      convert = fromKelvin.at(temperature);
      break;
    case TempType::Rankine:
      convert = fromRankine.at(temperature);
      break;
    case TempType::Delisle:
      convert = fromDelisle.at(temperature);
      break;
    case TempType::Newton:
      convert = fromNewton.at(temperature);
      break;
    case TempType::Reaumur:
      convert = fromReamur.at(temperature);
      break;
    case TempType::Romer:
      convert = fromRomer.at(temperature);
      break;
    default:
      return -1; // or throw an exception...
  }

  return convert(value);
}
```

Or even this:

```
double Temperature::convertTo(const TempType& temperature) const
{
  if (temperature == kind) {
    return value;
  }

  std::map<TempType, std::function<double(double)>> *convert;

  switch (kind) {
    case TempType::Celsius:
      convert = &fromCelsius;
      break;
    case TempType::Fahrenheit:
      convert = &fromFahrenheit;
      break;
    case TempType::Kelvin:
      convert = &fromKelvin;
      break;
    case TempType::Rankine:
      convert = &fromRankine;
      break;
    case TempType::Delisle:
      convert = &fromDelisle;
      break;
    case TempType::Newton:
      convert = &fromNewton;
      break;
    case TempType::Reaumur:
      convert = &fromReamur;
      break;
    case TempType::Romer:
      convert = &fromRomer;
      break;
    default:
      return -1; // or throw an exception...
  }

  return convert->at(temperature)(value);
}
```

This last case could then be simplified using a `std::map` of `std::map`, like @StoryTeller suggested in comments.

In any case, the `std::map` objects declared in the class should be `static` to avoid allocating new copies in every `Temperature` object you instantiate, like @1201ProgramAlarm suggested in comments:

```
class Temperature {
private:

  ...

  //conversion tables
  static std::map<TempType, std::function<double(double)>> fromCelsius = ...;    
  static std::map<TempType, std::function<double(double)>> fromFahrenheit = ...;    
  ... and so on ...
};
```

Comment: Yeah while testing I changed to "switch (kind)" because I figured out that the formulas I had gave me the result in the reverse direction. Thank you! Also yes it makes sense to have them static so I wont wste memory